# MongoDB: Find document in specific date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Following is the document structure:

```
{
    _id : '993920022',
    data: 'dkow000afkkaso',
    timeStamp : '3/7/2018 10:13:36 AM'
}
```

I want to find data in specific date range e.g. 01 Mar 2018 to 07 Mar 2018, but I am unable to achieve it, my MongoDB query is:

```
db.collection.find(
           {  'timeStamp' :
               {
                   $lte : Date('3/7/2018'),
                   $gte : Date('3/1/2018')
               }
           })
```

Answer (score 4):

If your timeStamp field is not a Date object but only a string I doubt that you can filter it by date with $lte and $gte without a conversion.
Probably a working approach could be using the **aggregation framework** with a **first stage of projection** where you convert the string in ISODate and a **second stage of match** where you do the filter.

Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $project: { data: "$data", timeStamp: ISODate("$timeStamp") } },
{ $match: { "timeStamp": { $lte: ISODate('3/7/2018'), $gte: ISODate('3/1/2018') }}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
let firstDate = new Date(pass value);
let lastDate = new Date(pass value);
db.collections.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":
            {
                "insertDate":
                    {
                        "$lte": lastDate,
                        "$gte": firstDate
                    }
            }
    }
])
.exec()
.then((result) => {
    //result
})
.catch((err) => {
    // error
});
```